# wrong output in converting date format data from an excel sheet to csv file in python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have this `excel` sheet and I am trying to convert this `excel` sheet to `csv` file. Among the columns in this sheet is a column with data in `date` format(like `7/4/2017`). I wrote this code but this is not converting the `date` field data correctly:

```
import xlrd
import csv

def Excel2CSV(ExcelFile, SheetName, CSVFile):

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFile)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(SheetName)
    csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'w',encoding='utf8')
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=';')

    for rownum in range(worksheet.nrows):
        wr.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))

    csvfile.close()
```

My sample data in excel is like this:

```
4/7/2017  value02  value03
4/5/2017  value12  value13
4/14/2017  value22  value23
4/10/2017  value32  value33
```

When I execute my above code this is what see in output:

```
42832.0;value02;value03
42830.0;value12;value13
42839.0;value22;value23
42835.0;value32;value33
```

As you can see that the date filed data is not getting converted correctly. What mistake I am making here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the XLRD package for reading the file you can find the answer at http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html

Basically dates are stored as 'number of days since.....' and just formatted to appear as dates when viewed in Excel.

There are more details here
http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-xlrd.xldate

'xldate_as_tuple' is the function you want

Comment: where does `xldate_as_tuple` needs to be applied as I am doing `wr.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))`?